# Can't find SDK source file

Tags: c++, sdk

I'm new to C++ and have some questions.  I downloaded a sdk (http://greenhouse.oblong.com/reference.html) to play with and have been running the samples successfully.  However I can't find the source code(.cpp or .c) anywhere only the header files.  I'm using Xcode on OS X and I'm only seeing .dylib files.  Can anyone explain how this works.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK you downloaded is a binary SDK; it includes everything you need to use it,
but it doesn't include the source code.

To build an example program with that SDK, try this:

```
$ cp -a /opt/oblong/greenhouse/samples .
$ cd samples
$ cd bob-ross
$ make
```

You should then be able to run the example with

```
$ ./bob-ross
```

You can also build it by loading samples/bob-ross/bob-ross.xcodeproj into XCode.